# Can I use this case in Neo4j database?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, nosql

Hello I am going to make a project for the faculty I am trying to make web app like [twoodo.com](https://www.twoodo.com/) 
so can I use Neo4j database in it? Can I save all conversations, dates, files, videos, photos, tasks, etc. or should I use another database? Can anyone guide me or help me. I am working with spring boot, angular too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: neo4j can store files, depending on what you have in mind; I would recommend starting with tutorials on angular and spring.  Which database to store this information in is only one small decision among many

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j can store different kinds of documents, but you would choose a graph database because of how the documents are related.  Other databases might be better for storing certain kinds of data; for example, neo4j does not handle nested documents as well as mongo or couchdb.  But neo4j is really good at linking and retrieving documents based on relationships.  For example, here's Michael Hunger modeling the entire database of 10M stackoverflow questions: http://neo4j.com/blog/import-10m-stack-overflow-questions/  Check some of his queries at the bottom showing off what you can do with relationship queries.  This kind of thing might be pretty solid in a twoodo app.

Comment: so can i save chat messages and newsfeed in neo4j or it will be miss ?

Comment: Yes, you can store chat messages and newsfeeds in neo4j.  You can model a sequence of messages or posts using 'next' relationships, so you can easily retrieve complete threads.  You can create users as nodes and link them to their posts.  Neo4j works well with large datasets.